# HDDRawCopy for backing up Rasperrry Pi SD cards

Tags: raspbian, backup

I routinely backup my Raspberry Pi SD card to my PC using HDDRawCopy.  It works fine and basically I'm happy.

However, several months ago I backed up one of my Pi's and proceeded to continue development work.  I decided to return to my backup, but wanted to keep the current SD card as is.  Thus I restored the backup copy to a new SD card.  That worked just fine and I took a different and better development path and then saved that copy over the original backup.

Now I have discovered that the current SD card is a 32 GB card, where the previous cards were 8 GB and thus the latest backup is for a 32 GB image.

Is there anyway to get an 8 GB image from either the current running (32 GB) SD card or from the HDDRawCopy image?

Thanks....RDK

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to use the SD Copy in the GUI of the latest [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/) to copy the card. This works even to different sized cards (obviously if big enough for the files).

Comment: OK, I will check this out.  I was not aware of this function in the startx GUI.  Is it on both Wheezy and Jessie?  Will the resulting SD card work for booting up the Pi? Thanks

Comment: @RDK Wheezy is obsolete and is definitely NOT "the latest Raspbian" It was introduced with the May release.